# how can i paste date in default in blade input

Tags: php, laravel, datepicker, laravel-blade

i am getting the date in blade form from controller in format like 2020-11-24(y-m-d) and i want to use this in input field value property

```
 <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <label>Surf Date <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="selectWrap pos-rel">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="surf_date" id="datepicker"
                                            value="{{ old('surf_date'),$posts->surf_start_date }}" required />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

but it does not working, in input field it shows mm/dd/yyyy by default

i have already used other methods like

```
                {{date_format(date_create($posts->surf_start_date),"m/d/Y")}}
                {{date('m/d/yy', strtotime($posts->surf_start_date))}}
                {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($posts->surf_start_date)->format('m/d/Y')}}
```

please help me out. thanks in advance

Comment: I think the problem is your datepicker js, show please let me know your JS script and what library you use .

Answer (score 0):

The input type date always take a `"YYYY-MM-DD"` format in value

pass the value as below.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" value="{{ date('Y-m-d',strtotime($posts->surf_start_date))}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error while using `old()`. Try correcting the syntax and see if it works

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Surf Date <span class="required">*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="selectWrap pos-rel">
            <input 
                class="form-control" 
                type="date" 
                name="surf_date" 
                id="datepicker"
                value="{{ old('surf_date', $posts->surf_start_date->format('Y-m-d')) }}" 
                required />
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```